# Could not append segments by Media Source API, get "InvalidStateError : An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-source

I use following sample program to append media files, but get "Uncaught InvalidStateError : An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" error at the first instant it hits code "mediaSource.sourceBuffers[0].appendBuffer(mediaSegment);". I am using Chrome 31.0.1650.57. Can anyone advice me to resolve this?

https://github.com/jbochi/media-source-playground/blob/master/test.html

I have done following modification to append files.

```
var buffer_len = 0;

function HaveMoreMediaSegments(){
    //return false; //return buffers.length > 0;
    return buffers.length > buffer_len;
}

// var GetNextMediaSegment = GetInitializationSegment;

function GetNextMediaSegment(){
    var buffer = buffers[buffer_len];
    buffers = buffers.slice(1);
    buffer_len = buffer_len + 1;
    return buffer;
}
```

And changed

```
mediaSource.sourceBuffers[0].append(mediaSegment);
```

to

```
mediaSource.sourceBuffers[0].appendBuffer(mediaSegment);
```

And

```
sourceBuffer.append(initSegment);
```

to

```
sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(initSegment);
```

As append method is not working in my environment.

And I use sourceopen instead of webkitsourceopen inside  window.setTimeout() event.

```
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', onSourceOpen.bind(this, video));
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that after you append data, the `SourceBuffer` instance becomes temporarily unusable while it's working. During this time, the `SourceBuffer`'s `updating` property will be set to `true`, so it's easy to check for.

But probably the simplest way to deal with this is to listen to the `updateend` event, and just queue up all your buffers and only append them when the `SourceBuffer` tells you it's ready for a new one. Like this:

```
// store the buffers until you're ready for them
var queue = [];

// whatever normally would have called appendBuffer(buffer) can 
// now just call queue.push(buffer) instead

sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function() {
  if ( queue.length ) {
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
  }
}, false);
```

Keep in mind that in order for the first event to fire, you need to append the first buffer manually, rather than pushing to `queue`. After that, just dump everything into the array.

Comment: if updateend fires and there is nothing in the queue and then you add something to the queue then it'll never be added to the sourcebuffer.

Comment: Sure. So, `queue.push = function( buffer ) { if ( !sourceBuffer.updating ) { sourceBuffer.appendBuffer( buffer ) } else { Array.prototype.push.call( this, buffer ) } }`

Answer (score -1):

Have you found the answer? Same problem here :(

I have a temporary solution which is setting setTimeout for each buffer append since you have to wait for previous buffer to finish updating (sourceBuffer.updating == false). The code may look like this:

```
var i = 0;
stream.on('data', function (buffer) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
    }, (i++) * 200);
});
```